# cassandra connection using soap web service

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am creating a web service that will authenticate login credentials of a website. In the web service, I am connecting to Cassandra through this code. This code works perfectly if I directly execute it through Java.

Below is the code I have used

```
Cluster cluster;
Session session;
cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("123.45.6.789").build();
session = cluster.connect("abcd");
```

When I run the Soap web service I get the below error

```
<faultstring>com/google/common/util/concurrent/AsyncFunction</faultstring>
```

My request message includes two parameters

```
<soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tom:userAuthentication>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>user2</arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>dtlworld</arg1>
      </tom:userAuthentication>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

Can anyone help me out where I am going wrong,

Thanks,
Raghu